# How to change start in dayGridWeek view when moving item on a day

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I am using fullcalendar dayGridWeek view. https://fullcalendar.io/docs/daygrid-view
When I move an item from one day to another day, the start time never changes, only the days gets changed.
I would like to detect on which position the event gets dropped.
If it is dropped above another event. Then I would like to update the start so it will fit before the other event.
If it is dropped below another event. Then I would like to update the start so it will fit after the other event.

I have checked the https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventDrop method, but this does not give information about where it gets dropped in relation of other events.

Does anybody has got an idea how to achieve this?

Comment: The dayGrid view has no concept of time at all. What you're saying doesn't make sense...even if you drop something "before" another event, there's still no defined start time. e.g. is it 1 hour before the other event? Or 7.5 hours before? Or what? It's impossible for the calendar to know precisely what is intended. If you want to achieve it so that you can drop it onto a specific time, use the timeGrid view instead.

Comment: @ADyson I would like to use the dayGridWeek view, because I want to list events with a short duration. A timeGrid view is not suitable for this. I just want to know where a event is dropped relative to other events, so I could adjust the start time to or needs.

Comment: `I want to list events with a short duration`...that's exactly what timeGrid is for. You can adjust the slot duration in the display to your needs, if you need it to show more fine-grained intervals.

Comment: `I just want to know where a event is dropped relative to other events`...well you can't, because the dayGrid has no concept of time. It can't tell you precisely where the event was dropped on, because it doesn't record that information (because it can't, because there are no time slots). Why not let the user set precisely where they want to drop the event, by using a time grid? Rather than having to have extra code to adjust it afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this behavior, you can use the eventOverlap callback in FullCalendar. This callback function is called whenever an event is being dropped and is used to determine whether the event should overlap with other events or not.

Within the eventOverlap function, you can access the other events that are present at the drop location using the stagedEvent and existingEvent arguments. These arguments represent the event that is being dropped and the event that it is overlapping with, respectively.

Based on the position of the dropped event relative to the existing event, you can update the start time of the dropped event so that it fits before or after the existing event. To update the start time of the event, you can use the updateEvent method of the FullCalendar instance.

Here's an example of how you can implement this behavior:

```
var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
  // ... other options ...
  eventOverlap: function(stagedEvent, existingEvent) {
    if (stagedEvent.id !== existingEvent.id) {
      // check if the staged event overlaps with the existing event
      var stagedEventStart = stagedEvent.start;
      var stagedEventEnd = stagedEvent.end;
      var existingEventStart = existingEvent.start;
      var existingEventEnd = existingEvent.end;

      var overlaps = (stagedEventStart < existingEventEnd) && (stagedEventEnd > existingEventStart);

      if (overlaps) {
        // check if the staged event is dropped above or below the existing event
        var stagedEventTop = $(stagedEvent.el).offset().top;
        var existingEventTop = $(existingEvent.el).offset().top;

        if (stagedEventTop < existingEventTop) {
          // move the staged event to fit before the existing event
          var newStart = existingEventStart;
          calendar.updateEvent({ id: stagedEvent.id, start: newStart });
        } else {
          // move the staged event to fit after the existing event
          var newStart = existingEventEnd;
          calendar.updateEvent({ id: stagedEvent.id, start: newStart });
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

In this example, we are checking if the staged event overlaps with the existing event using the start and end times of the events. If there is an overlap, we are then checking if the staged event is dropped above or below the existing event by comparing the vertical positions of the events on the page using jQuery's offset method.

If the staged event is dropped above the existing event, we update the start time of the staged event to fit before the existing event using the updateEvent method. If the staged event is dropped below the existing event, we update the start time of the staged event to fit after the existing event.

Note that the eventOverlap callback is called for every event that the staged event overlaps with, so you may need to adjust the start time of the staged event multiple times if it overlaps with multiple events.